# Find the sum of the following series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k-3^k}{5^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the sum but am struggling to figure out the correct approach.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4^k-3^k}{5^k}
$$

Comment: Two geometric series. Can be done in one's head.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Man you must have a big head !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^k-3^k}{5^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^k - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{3}{5}\bigg)^k$$

$$= \frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{5}} - \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{5}} = 5 - \frac{5}{2} = \frac{5}{2}$$

Where the second equality is just from the geometric series formula.

Comment: This is perfect, cannot believe I didn't see that this was a geometric series. I think the n-1 in the ar^n-1 notation in my textbook is what is confusing me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Note that both $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{4^k}{5^k}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{3^k}{5^k}$ converge absolutely. Therefore their difference converges. Can you proceed?

Comment: You don't really need absolute convergence to prove that $\sum (a_n-b_n) = \sum a_n - \sum b_n$. Just convergence.

Answer (score 3):

These are two convergent geometric series combined.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^k-3^k}{5^k} & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^k}{5^k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^k}{5^k}\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k\\
\end{align*}
The reason you can split this is because both the series are convergent ($|r|<1$). Now use the sum of Geometric series to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^k=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5}}-\frac{1}{\frac{2}{5}}=5-\frac{5}{2}=\frac{5}{2}$$